# unable to get value from promise when returing

Tags: javascript, promise

i have function that will get the sum of data on a specific period

```
  const cashData = db.query(`SELECT SUM (payments_log.amount_paid) FROM payments_log WHERE payments_log.payment_method = '2' AND payments_log.inserted_at BETWEEN $1 AND NOW() `, [date])
.then(records => {
  return records[0].sum
})
.catch(error => {
  cb(new Error(`Print failed: ${error}`))
})
```

but when i run it my result is[object promise]. Why is that?

Comment: You are suppose to process `records[0].sum` in that call back function. If you really want to use like that then `.then(records => {
  return records[0].sum
}).then(res => { // your sum here })
.catch(error => {
  cb(new Error(`Print failed: ${error}`))
})`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until promise finished:

```
  const cashData = db.query(`SELECT SUM (payments_log.amount_paid) FROM payments_log WHERE payments_log.payment_method = '2' AND  payments_log.inserted_at BETWEEN $1 AND NOW() `, [date])
   .then(records => {
     return records[0].sum
 })
  .catch(error => {
    cb(new Error(`Print failed: ${error}`))
 });

 cashData.then(res => console.log(res));
```

[Promise Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to process `records[0].sum` in that call back function. If you really want to use like that then use below

```
.then(records => { return records[0].sum })
.then(res => { // your sum here })
.catch(error => { cb(new Error(Print failed: ${error})) })
```